# Colorbox make the light box fixed when scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I working with jquery colorbox. When the page content is big and colorbox is opened. Then the color box scrolled along with the page content. I want the colorbox need to be fixed even the background content scrolls.

Please help me out to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puaka i am changing a little thing, which make it works awesome. It aligns center perfectly.

Change the colorbox.css

from

```
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
```

to

```
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay{position:fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
#cboxWrapper{}
```

colorbox is perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 23):

perhaps all of these answers are from an earlier version of colorbox, but the "fixed" parameter is now available as of version 1.3.17:

```
$("a.item").colorbox({fixed:true});
```

no more mucking about in the CSS required!  Thanks colorbox guys!

Comment: if you make it fixed - you can't scroll down to see whole image if you have a really high one and you don't want to scale it down

Comment: @Picard fixed is best used in combination with maxHeight and maxWidth. Set those to 90% or something similar and it will scale down images that are too big for the user's screen.

Answer (score 2):

try this. change the colorbox.css the first css rule :

from

```
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
```

to

```
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
#cboxWrapper { position:fixed; margin:0 auto; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: in this case, the wrapper is not position center and middle for the width and height respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will also be helpful.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.div-container').colorbox( {

        initialWidth:'550px', 
        initialHeight:'350px', 
        onComplete: function() {
            // alert('window = ' + $(window).height());
            // alert('colorbox = ' + $('#colorbox').height());

            var window_height = $(window).height();
            var colorbox_height = $('#colorbox').height();
            var top_position = 0;

            if(window_height > colorbox_height) {
                top_position = (window_height - colorbox_height) / 2;
            }

            // alert(top_position);
            $('#colorbox').css({'top':top_position, 'position':'fixed'});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

puaka method only worked if I was scrolled all the way to the top.
else the box would appear lower down.

i devised another method.

```
$("#btn").colorbox({width:"90%", height:"90%", iframe:true, scrolling:false, onOpen:function() { $("body").css("overflow", "hidden"); }, onClosed:function() { $("body").css("overflow", "auto"); }});
```

onOpen remove the body's scrollbar
onClosed replace the scrollbar

Comment: this is the best way to go about it, when using in Chrome through, onClose creates a NEW scrollbar. The property for on Closed should be "visible", not "auto";

Answer (score 0):

This one works even better for me:

```
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay{position:fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
#cboxWrapper{position:fixed;}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on bradaric idea, you might need to change

```
        posTop = Math.max(winHeight - settings.h - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight,0)/2 + $window.scrollTop(),
        posLeft = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth - settings.w - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth,0)/2 + $window.scrollLeft();
```

to

```
        posTop = Math.max(winHeight - settings.h - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight,0)/2,
        posLeft = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth - settings.w - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth,0)/2;
```

in the position function. (Works for me)

Answer (score 0):

```
posTop = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight - settings.h - loadedHeight - interfaceHeight,0)/2,
posLeft = Math.max($window.width()  - settings.w - loadedWidth - interfaceWidth,0)/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The css fix above works perfectly fine for Mozilla and Chrome, but in IE it gives some padding problem if the event takes place in between the page. U can extend the function by using hooks and hide the overflow when the colorbox is opened. Example :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $(document).bind('cbox_open', function(){
        $('body').css({overflow:'hidden'})
});
    });
```

the above code adds style overflow:hidden to the body, if u close the colorbox you may find the scroll is not there on the page, so for that you should add this line as well in $(document).ready(function() .

```
$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){
        $('body').css({overflow:'visible'})
});
```

Comment: this code works ONLY if the element opening has not already caused the user to scroll

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the above methods are not fit to Colorbox fixed when scrolled. The following method, I've tested on all browsers (IE7 and larger):

```
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay {
  position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999;  
  }
#cboxWrapper {                       
  position:fixed; top:50%; left:50%; 
  margin:-25% 0 0 -25%; /*margin default */
  z-index:9999;
  }                                                 

/* not overflow hidden share, Opera truncates everything else */

              $("a.cBox").colorbox({
                 width:"500",
                 height:"400",
                 iframe:true,
                 onOpen: function() {
                 $('#cboxWrapper').css('margin','-200px 0 0 -250px');  
                 // margin adjusted - half the width and height minus margin top/left
                 }
              });
```

This method works blendent