# ColorBox positioned incorrectly due to scroll bar and scrolled page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, colorbox

[If I keep the entire page visible (without scroll bars)](http://graham-russell.co.uk/colorbox/), ColorBox behaves as expected.

When a scroll bar is visible on the right, page content shifts, but colourbox does not.

Attempted to fix this with html {overflow-y: scroll;}, but this does not seem to work. Page content is fixed correctly, but ColorBox does not respect the scrollbar width.

If scroll bar is visible, and the page is scrolled down when the link is clicked, ColorBox initialises in the wrong position, taking its TOP alignment from the top of the VISIBLE page, not the actual page.

EDIT:

On line 492, there is is the following code
`// remove the modal so that it doesn't influence the document width/height
        $box.css({top: -9e4, left: -9e4});`

I seems that the modal IS affecting the document width/height, as commenting out line 503 produces the desired effect `//top = scrollTop;`.  This tells me that the modal box is causing issues.  This still doesn't correct the behavior of the horizontal alignment, the popup is still offset from the body as it's not taking the scroll bar into account.

Any idea?

Comment: is this browser-dependent behaviour? could not reproduce in IE 9 and Firefox 14.

Comment: This behavior hold true for FF v16.0.2, Safari v5.0.5 and IE v9.0.8.  I am guessing it's a CSS issue.

Just be clear, if you resize your browser window so there is a scroll bar visible on the right, scroll down the page before clicking the link, you should be able to reproduce what I am seeing.

Answer (score 0):

It`s default behaviour of the ColorBox. To deal with it you need to change ColorBox initialization to (snippet was taken from your page):

```
.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"800px", height:"600px", top:"137px", opacity:"0", scrolling:"false", position:fixed});
```

Pay attention to `position:fixed` property - it forces browser to treat your `top` param as you require, ie it will be always 137px, not 137px + scrolled height of the page.

Please also consider this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712036/colorbox-make-the-light-box-fixed-when-scrolling) as similar to yours.

Comment: This is actually the opposite to the behavior I was hoping to achieve.  My intent is for the popup to open exactly over the box containing the link.  Using the `fixed:true` argument, the popup doesn't scroll with the page, it remains fixed in the browser.

The call I'm using works, as long as the page has no scroll bars in operation.  The only way around this I can see is to set the page to `overflow: hidden` which I would rather not do.